# Are all random variables have the same distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

In [this paper](https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~clenzen/pubs/LW11mis.pdf), a variation of *Chernoff bound* has been introduced.

For $N$ independent 0–1 random variables $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{N}$ define $X=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{i}$. Then with high probability we have

$X \in E[X] + O\big(log(n) + \sqrt{E[X]log(n)}\big)$

I have 2 questions.

1. Are all random variables have the same distribution $Bin(1,p)$? Can they have different distributions ($X_{1}\sim Bin(1,p_{1}),X_{2}\sim Bin(1,p_{2}),...,X_{N}\sim Bin(1,p_{N})$)?
2. What is the meaning of $\in$? Does this mean $X\in \big[E[X] - O\big(log(n) + \sqrt{E[X]log(n)}\big),E[X] + O\big(log(n) + \sqrt{E[X]log(n)}\big)\big]$ ?

Comment: Is it possible you typed $\in$ when you meant $\le?$ See Wikipedia on 'Chernoff bound'.